# Accessing data from ROOM DB using ViewModel and ID

Tags: android, viewmodel, dao, android-room

Suppose I have got a list of data in the Room DB.
Let the data be: setId, formId, formName.
There can be multiple formId in the single setId. Let setId 1 contains 10 forms, 2 contains 5 forms.

Now what I wanna do is, extract the data from the db using the setId in the ViewModel.

Let my dao be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM form WHERE setId = :id")
LiveData<List<Form>> getAllFilledForms(int id);
```

How can I implement such action in ViewModel.
I want to retrieve all the list of the forms where the set id is same, let 1.

Edit:
ViewModel Class:

```java
public class ListSetViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final LiveData < List < FormSet >> allFormSets;
    private FormDatabase formDatabase;
    public ListSetViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        formDatabase = FormDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        allFormSets = formDatabase.formSetDao().getAllFilledForms(setId);
    }

    public LiveData < List < FormSet >> getAllFormSets(setId) {
        return allFormSets;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your method returning? can you specify actual problem with your code.

Comment: My method returns the List of the Forms as per the setId. What I intend to do is, get the List of the forms from DB using the setId. I am confused in the actual implementation of such actions in the ViewModel.



Is it possible to retrieve the data from the db using the Android ViewModel by passing the parameter in the ViewModel?

Comment: aren't already passing value of setid to your viewmodel method? `getAllFormSets(setId)` what this method is taking as parameter?

Comment: I am confused at that point. 
Am I missing something there?

Comment: how are you calling that method from your activity? you should already be passing a value over that that is filtering your data.

Comment: 'allFormSets = formDatabase.formSetDao().getAllFilledForms(setId);'

this line gives me the error. 
Am I doing something wrong here. Would be glad if you can explain. :)

Comment: so this is returning you `allFormSets` based on `setId` that you are passing. if you change value of `setId` it will change your output. `setId` is your normal variable right?

Comment: yes, setId is the one I want to pass from the activity, and get the returned list.
Actually setId is the variable that I want to pass from the activity.

Comment: you are already doing that.

Comment: I can give you a link of my Repo of Github for Room Implementation with explanation which will help you if you don't mind?

Comment: thanks... would be glad. @UmangBurman

Comment: Here it is: [Github Link](https://github.com/umangburman/Room-Library-Login-Example) --- [Medium Blog](https://medium.com/@umang.burman.micro/android-room-persistence-library-a-login-example-with-livedata-b6019fe23b0)

Comment: thanks @UmangBurman

Comment: Please comment back if it is useful in anyway possible.. :) thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject your ViewModel with an ID by a Factory or Dagger2. Or you can use a public method to get data.

```
public LiveData<List<FormSet>> getAllFormSets(setId){
    return allFormSets = formDatabase.formSetDao().getAllFilledForms(setId);
}
```